Calculate difference between multiple changing columns in R
I have a dataframe (df) in R with 7 columns



ID
Year1
Year2
Year3
Size1
Size2
Size3




A
2021
2022
NA
10
15
NA


B
2022
2023
2024
20
21
25


C
2021
2022
NA
5
20
NA



I want to add an 8th column called 'difference' that gives me the growth rate for each individual, which would be (size 3 - size 1) / (year 3 - year 1). I was able to do that with this code:
df2 <- df %>%
  mutate(difference = (df$Size3 -df$Size1)/(df$Year3 - df$Year1))

However, some individuals only have year 1 and year 2. How can I write a statement saying if Year3 = NA, then make the 'difference' column from (Size2 - Size1) / (Year2 - Year1)?
Desired output:



ID
Year 1
Year 2
Year 3
Size 1
Size 2
Size 3
Difference




A
2021
2022
NA
10
15
NA
5


B
2022
2023
2024
20
21
25
2.5


C
2021
2022
NA
5
20
NA
15




The headers in the expected output are not the same as in the input.

You can try ifelse
transform(
  df,
  Difference = ifelse(
    is.na(Year3),
    (Size2 - Size1) / (Year2 - Year1),
    (Size3 - Size1) / (Year3 - Year1)
  )
)

which gives
  ID Year1 Year2 Year3 Size1 Size2 Size3 Difference
1  A  2021  2022    NA    10    15    NA        5.0
2  B  2022  2023  2024    20    21    25        2.5
3  C  2021  2022    NA     5    20    NA       15.0


This may not matter but if Size3 is NA and Year3 is not NA it will return NA rather than the ratio involving Size2 and Year2.

@G.Grothendieck yes, that might be a possible situation where my colde doesn't fit. I just followed OP's words: "How can I write a statement saying if Year3 = NA, then make the 'difference' column from (Size2 - Size1) / (Year2 - Year1)?"

If, as in the question, it is always true that either both or neither of Year3 and Size3 are NA then we can use coalesce.  coalesce returns its first argument if it is not NA and its second argument otherwise.  Input is provided in Note at the end.
library(dplyr)

# check that both or neither Year3 and Size3 are NA
with(df, all(is.na(Year3) == is.na(Size3)))
## [1] TRUE

df %>%
  mutate(Difference = (coalesce(Size3, Size2) - Size1) / 
    (coalesce(Year3, Year2) - Year1))
##   ID Year1 Year2 Year3 Size1 Size2 Size3 Difference
## 1  A  2021  2022    NA    10    15    NA        5.0
## 2  B  2022  2023  2024    20    21    25        2.5
## 3  C  2021  2022    NA     5    20    NA       15.0

Variation
If x is NA then 0*x is NA and otherwise is zero so we can write this which will work even if Year3 and Size3 are not both NA or not NA.
df %>%
  mutate(Difference = (coalesce(Size3 + 0*Year3, Size2) - Size1) / 
    (coalesce(Year3 + 0*Size3, Year2) - Year1))

Note
The input in reproducible form:
df <- data.frame(
  ID = c("A", "B", "C"),
  Year1 = c(2021L, 2022L, 2021L),
  Year2 = c(2022L, 2023L, 2022L),
  Year3 = c(NA, 2024L, NA),
  Size1 = c(10L, 20L, 5L),
  Size2 = c(15L, 21L, 20L),
  Size3 = c(NA, 25L, NA)
)

